# Convert xpath -q -e command to xmllint --xpath one

Tags: xml, linux, xpath, xml-parsing

I´m very fresh in XML files and would like to convert this command :

**xpath -q -e "/ns2:softwareSystem/module/rootPath[not(@xsi:type)]/@name"\ file.xml**

to this one **xmllint --xpath**

here is an example : https://github.com/apache/phoenix/pull/170/commits/16059876613ecb3a13b086adad9a8a861f04d1dc

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is :

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='softwareSystem']/module/rootPath[not(@*[local-name()='type'])]/@name" file.xml
```

Note that using `local-name()` is generally not recommended when you can declare namespaces in the application.

If you can, it's probably better to use `xmlstarlet` since namespaces and namespace prefixes are better [handled](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html#idm47077139530992) (you can use `/ns2:softwareSystem` directly or `/_:softwareSystem`).

**EDIT** : If you're dealing with a variable (for e.g. : `variable="foo"`), you can use something like this :

```
xmllint --xpath "string(//*[local-name()='softwareSystem']/module[@name='"$variable"']/@id)" file.xml
```

Comment: what about this which has a variable **xpath -q -e "string(/ns2:softwareSystem/module[@name=\"$variable\"]/@id)" file.xml**

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanke a lot @E.Wiest

Comment: Could you please see this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63279657/how-to-add-break-line-in-xmllint-command)