# how to add break line in xmllint command

Tags: xml, xpath, xmllint

I have the following command

```
xmllint --xpath "//*[local-name()='softwareSystem']/module/rootPath[not(@*[local-name()='type'])]/@name" file.xml
```

and would like to sperate each module (every matching) on a new line

thanks for help

Comment: If you don't get an answer using xmllint, try switching to xmlstarlet or xidel.

Comment: Do I need to change the syntax as well ? because I never used xmlstarlet. or could you please edit my command by using xmlstarlet with new line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have your html so I have to guess, but with xmlstarlet, for example, try something like:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//*[local-name()='softwareSystem']/module/rootPath[not(@*[local-name()='type'])]" -v $'concat(@name,"\n")' file.xml
```

or

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//*[local-name()='softwareSystem']/module/rootPath[not(@*[local-name()='type'])]" -v $@name file.xml -n file.xml
```

and see if it works.

Comment: What about this command can you convert it : xpath -q -e "/ns2:softwareSystem/module/rootPath[not(@xsi:type)]/@name" file.xml

Comment: @Stephan Possibly; but it would help to see some of the xml involved (namespaces are always a problem, unfortunately) and, any case, you should post it as a separate question.

Comment: do not respond with a question on an answer give, but inform why the answer is applicable to you , or not, and state WHY it is not applicable!